# Setup project for both selenium and jsdom testing env

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I would like to chose on witch jsenv i will run my test with command line.

I have already setup my two env:

`jsEnv in Test := new org.scalajs.jsenv.jsdomnodejs.JSDOMNodeJSEnv()`

and

`jsEnv in Test := BrowserStackRunner.load()` // selenium

how I can select witch one to use in command line?

Ideally i would like something like `sbt test:jsdom` and `sbt test:selenium`

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `set` command of sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Commands+for+managing+the+build+definition):

```
$ sbt 'set jsEnv in Test := new org.scalajs.jsenv.jsdomnodejs.JSDOMNodeJSEnv()' test
$ sbt 'set jsEnv in Test := BrowserStackRunner.load()' test
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine in a unix env, but not in windows, neither using intellij configuration

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` if it needs to work on Windows as well.